# ForegroundColorSpan is not applied to ReplacementSpan

Tags: android, spannablestring

I'm trying to utilize ReplacementSpans to format the input in a EditText Field (without modifying the content):

```
public class SpacerSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return (int) paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start,end)+" ");
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawText(text.subSequence(start,end)+" ", 0, 2, x, y, paint);
    }
}
```

This works as expected and adds spacing after the spanned section.
However, if I also apply a ForegroundColorSpan the color is not set for the spanned section:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

SpannableString content = new SpannableString("1234567890");

ForegroundColorSpan fontColor = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
SpacerSpan spacer = new SpacerSpan();
content.setSpan(fontColor, 0, content.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
content.setSpan(spacer, 4, 5, Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);

edit.setText(content);
```

The Result looks like http://i.cubeupload.com/4Us5Zj.png

If I apply a AbsoluteSizeSpan the specified font size is also applied to the Replacement Span section. Is this the intended behavior, am I missing something, or a bug in android?

Comment: Since the only concrete implementations of `ReplacementSpan` in the SDK are for replacing text with images, it may be that this stuff hasn't been tested all that well for replacing text with more text. One difference between `ForegroundColorSpan` and `AbsoluteSizeSpan` is that the latter overrides both `updateMeasureState()` and `updateDrawState()`, while `ForegroundColorSpan` only overrides `updateDrawState()`. This makes sense, in that the foreground color does not affect measurements. However, it is possible that the `Paint` passed into `draw()` is the wrong one.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the ```Paint``` that is passed to ```draw()``` is a different one (Output if i log the paint that is set):
```ForegroundColor. r: 0, g: 255, b: 0```
```Color during draw. r: 0, g: 0, b: 0```

Comment: As a test, you could try creating a subclass of `ForegroundColorSpan` that overrides `updateMeasureState()` to do what `updateDrawState()` does, then try applying your subclass instead of `ForegroundColorSpan`. If your subclass works, the good news is that you will know for certain the source of the problem. The bad news is that you may lose your subclass if the `Spanned` gets passed through a `Bundle`, as only built-in `ParcelableSpans` are supported for that AFAIK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CommonWare pointed me in the right direction.
It seems like `ReplacementSpans` are rendered before any `CharacterStyleSpan` are consulted [1]

A possible (but ugly) fix is to implement a custom `ForegroundColorSpan` that extends `MetricAffectingSpan` (MetricAffectingSpans are consulted before ReplacementSpans are drawn [1]).

```
public class FontColorSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {

    private int mColor;

    public FontColorSpan(int color) {
        mColor = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint textPaint) {
        textPaint.setColor(mColor);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint) {
        textPaint.setColor(mColor);
    }
}
```

I guess this is a bug that should be reported?

[1]http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/text/TextLine.java#936

Comment: This also explains why the ```AbsoluteSizeSpan``` was applied (it extends ```MetricAffectingSpan```)