# Dotted underline in TextView using SpannableString in Android

Tags: java, android, underline, spannablestring

I want dotted underline below SpannableString
Like here is my string

```
Hello, How are you?
```

I want to develop dotted underline below `How` word so how to set it? 
If i add clickable that its give me underline but i want dotted underline below `How` word.
Can anyone help me ?
Actually on click of that `How` word i am opening a dialog so that thing i achieved with clickable but i want to design that `How` word with dotted underline.

**Editted:**
Using below post dotted underline appears but text color is not showing using ForegroundColorSpan class. can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375638/custom-span-underline-text-with-dotted-line-android

Comment: you want to underline a word and make it clickable too ?

Comment: @VikasTiwari I already tried this but it's not properly showing output. and in my case may be more than one word has dotted underline so in this case its not properly showing.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi yes i want both underline and clickable also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use two `SpannableString` for it as

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello, how are you ?");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
         //perform operation on click

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 9, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light)), 0, 9, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView_understand.setText(ss);
    textView_understand.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView_understand.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    textView_understand
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                //On click
                }
            });
```

And for make it dotted underline you should use

```
private static class DottedUnderlineSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
private Paint p;
private int mWidth;
private String mSpan;

private float mSpanLength;
private boolean mLengthIsCached = false;

public DottedUnderlineSpan(int _color, String _spannedText){
    p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(_color);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{mDashPathEffect, mDashPathEffect}, 0));
    p.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    mSpan = _spannedText;
}

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    mWidth = (int) paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    return mWidth;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    if(!mLengthIsCached)
        mSpanLength = paint.measureText(mSpan);

    // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944
    // canvas.drawLine can't draw dashes when hardware acceleration is enabled,
    // but canvas.drawPath can
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x, y + mOffsetY);
    path.lineTo(x + mSpanLength, y + mOffsetY);
    canvas.drawPath(path, this.p);
}
}
```

and use this class for span as:

```
  DottedUnderlineSpan dottedUnderlineSpan = new DottedUnderlineSpan(0xFF00FF00, spannedText);
```

To make your underline look the same on all densities set that dimens in dp

```
mStrokeWidth = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.stroke_width);
mDashPathEffect = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dash_path_effect);
mOffsetY = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.offset_y);
```

Comment: can you plz give me value of `mDashPathEffect`, `mDashPathEffect`, `mOffsetY`,`mStrokeWidth`

Comment: I know you pick answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375638/custom-span-underline-text-with-dotted-line-android post, I already tried. See my question's comment

Comment: but atleast try spannable strings first then make it dotted. Go step by step. I'm here to help, don't worry.

Comment: mStrokeWidth = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.stroke_width);
mDashPathEffect = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dash_path_effect);
mOffsetY = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.offset_y);

can you plz give me proper value. it would be great help if you provide me proper value

Comment: Don't make it dotted first.

Comment: I alreay developed everything just remain to generate dotted underline

Comment: Join a chat room with me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100651/android-talkies .

Comment: I tried now I got a proper working solution. I found one mistake that I did previously. I am passing whole text inside dottedUnderlineSpan's constructor. so now what i did i passed only that word which i want to show dotted underline.

Comment: Its working perfect now. just I need to check with all the scenario. thx for your help

Comment: One more problem I am facing now that after applying dotted underline I am unable to set text color for that text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141414/discussion-between-sanjay-prajapati-and-anshul-tyagi).

Comment: text color issue I resolved by http://stackoverflow.com/a/28329166/7075032 answer.

Comment: glad to hear that :D

Comment: dotted underline working fine, but dotted underlined textview not wrapping to the next line