# ForegroundColorSpan not working if i set Custom ReplacementSpan in SpannableString of textview android

Tags: android, spannablestring

Below code is set up dotted underline in spannableString

```
private static class DottedUnderlineSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    private Paint p;
    private int mWidth;
    private String mSpan;

    private float mSpanLength;
    private boolean mLengthIsCached = false;

    private float mOffsetY;

    public DottedUnderlineSpan(int _color, String _spannedText, float dashPathEffect,
                               float strokeWidth, float offsetY) {
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(_color);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{dashPathEffect, dashPathEffect}, 0));
        p.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        mSpan = _spannedText;
        mOffsetY = offsetY;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                       Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        mWidth = (int) paint.measureText(text, start, end);
        return mWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top,
                     int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
        if (!mLengthIsCached)
            mSpanLength = paint.measureText(mSpan);

        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944
        // canvas.drawLine can't draw dashes when hardware acceleration is enabled,
        // but canvas.drawPath can
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x, y + mOffsetY);
        path.lineTo(x + mSpanLength, y + mOffsetY);
        canvas.drawPath(path, this.p);
    }
}
```

Here I call above class and set dotted underline.

```
SpannableString spannableText = new SpannableString("Hello, How are you");
spannableText.setSpan(new DottedUnderlineSpan(fromColor("#b5d189"), "How", dashPathEffect,strokeWidth, offsetY),7,9,0);
spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(fromColor("#7ac902")),7, 9,0);
textView.setText(spannableText);
textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Here my problem is ForegroundColorSpan is not working I don't know why?
If I remove

```
spannableText.setSpan(new DottedUnderlineSpan(fromColor("#b5d189"), "How", dashPathEffect,strokeWidth, offsetY),7,9,0);
```

the code then ForegroundColorspan working perfectly.

I want `How` word in green color with dotted underline.
can anybody help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28329166/7075032
The Answer here helped to resolve this issue

Comment: @ManojFrekzz I guess you did not see my first comment.

Comment: marked as duplicate by Community♦ 1 min ago